# How do I use Spy++ on this menu that keeps disappearing if I click outside of it?

Tags: c++, winapi, spy++

I want to log the messages of this menu using Spy++.

[image]

Usually, if I want to log the messages of a window, I would use Spy++ and drag the "Find Window" tool over it. But in this case, if I drag the tool over this menu, the menu disappears because I clicked outside it.

[image]

Is there any workaround to this?

A little more information:

What I want to achieve is finding out what messages are sent when I click the menu's items (they are buttons).

That particular menu in the first picture is created only when I click the button, and it has a different `HWND` every time I click it.

If I can't accomplish this in Spy++, can I do this using some other application similar to Spy++?

Comment: If you can't achieve what you want with Spy++, you can still write a small application to do it. This app could have a timer, in the timer's callback enumerate all windows [1], and select the one with the desired properties, like window class name, position, or children -- or a combination of these that's unique to this menu window. If you find the window based on these properties, you will have its HWND and you can start capturing its messages. / [1] Your application could also regularly enumerate the child windows of the Zoom app.

Comment: @kol rather than polling windows in a timer, I prefer to let the OS notify me when a new window is created, such as with a WH_CBT hook, or a WinEvents hook

Comment: @RemyLebeau My comment was based on a distant memory... Many years ago I wrote an application called PopupKiller which used polling to automatically find and close Internet Explorer popup windows (which were opened by an IE automation app we used for website monitoring). It worked well, but I totally agree with you that getting notified is always better than polling.

Comment: Zoom doesn't use standard Windows controls. Using Spy++ on it isn't going to uncover anything interesting. Its menu implementation doesn't use standard window messages. Which bears the question: What are you really trying to accomplish? In all likeliness, the answer to the *real* question is going to be [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: I think you can do renaming using the Zoom API, but I don't have a license for it :(

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to rename a particular participant. But the thing is, I don't know a proper way to find the position of the rename button for the participant because the participant's name is in a scroll pane, and that scroll pane isn't accessible through winapi. I tried using UI Automation, but it doesn't return all the participant components like i want it to. That is why i want to try my luck in sending the same message as the rename button.

Comment: If UI Automation doesn't work, and the application in question doesn't provide a custom automation interface, nor uses standard windows controls then there isn't a whole lot you can do.

Comment: @IInspectabl do you think its possible to emulate a function of this app by sending the same messages you find in spy++ to the application? I've been trying to deduce how it does it by going through spy++ logs since a week, but i have had no luck yet.

Comment: *"do you think its possible to emulate a function of this app by sending the same messages"* - That is based on the assumption that application were to actually use window messages. That assumption may likely prove to be wrong. If you want to deduce how the application does certain things, you're going to have to reverse engineer its implementation. Depending on your local legislation this may or may not be legal.

Comment: I don't really care about legality, i just want to automate it. I was able to automate what I wanted to through a very crude solution using UI Automation and winapi. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out myself.
You can just log messages of the parent window with the logging options set to also log messages of child windows.